# CRUD from external php file

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to outsource `page.php`'s CRUD functions to `functions.php`, which is included in the former?

An example of this would be

## `functions.php`

```
<?php
function store($tablename,$db,$id,$input,$coltype)
{
  $updateQ = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s = %s WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($tablename, "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($coltype, "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($input, "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($id, "int"));
  mysqli_select_db($db, $conn);
  $result = mysqli_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
  return $result;
}
?>
```

Finally, `functions.php` is included in `page.php`, and the `store` function is simply called, to keep the display page relatively free of php code.

Would such a thing be possible/feasible to do which includes retrieving data as well? If yes, How would the resultset be returned and how can it be navigated?

My biggest constraint is that I cannot use a framework here, and some of the solutions I found online are to use frameworks like `laravel` which have boiler plate code ready.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? (Hint: Look at `include()`, `include_once()`, `require()` and `require_once()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include`/`require` basically take the contents of the file being included, and treat it as if those those contents were literally part of the parent file. There's no functional difference between:

single_script.php:

```
<?php

function foo(...) { ...}

foo();
```

and

foo.php:

```
<?php
function foo(...) { ...}
```

main.php:

```
<?php
include('foo.php');
foo();
```

Comment: That was a far simpler explanation than I'd hoped for, Thank you very much! So am I right to say that the scope of both pages extend to the entirety of each other?

Comment: "Scope" is probably not the right word, but yes. Also, order doesn't matter either. Function definitions can follow their calls.

Comment: it DOES matter when the function's defined in the external file. `foo(); include('file_that_defines_foo.php');` won't work - the include won't have been executed/parsed yet at that point.